# Are the factors in the de Broglie identities operators, scalar real numbers, or both? Or something else?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-gravity

I understand that $\hbar$ is an honest element of $\mathbb{R}$. But I am trying to understand how the de Broglie wavelength is related to the wave function mathematically. In the identity $p = \hbar k$, which of the following are true?

1. $p$ and $k$ should be understood as operators or,
2. $p$ and $k$ should be understood as the expected values $\langle p \rangle$ and $\langle k \rangle$ of the wave function.
3. $p$ and $k$ are elements of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for $k \geq 1$ but are not the expected values of momentum and wave number.

If the answer depends on whether the particle is relativistic or non relativistic, space time is curved or flat, please answer the question in each case.

Comment: If it is true in the operator sense (1), it automatically follows by taking expectations that it is true in the sense of expected values (2). For the third, in the version de Broglie had in mind historically, $p$ and $k$ where considered as real number vectors and that's how he conceived his relation. But in modern quantum mechanics, the base statement would be in terms of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP is asking what is the precise meaning of momentum and wave-number being related through Plank's constant:

1. An identity on operators,
   $$
   \hat{\boldsymbol p}=\hbar\hat{\boldsymbol k}\tag1
   $$
2. An identity on their eigenvalues,
   $$
   \boldsymbol p=\hbar\boldsymbol k\tag2
   $$
   where $\hat{\boldsymbol p}|\boldsymbol p\rangle=\boldsymbol p|\boldsymbol p\rangle$ and $\hat{\boldsymbol k}|\boldsymbol k\rangle=\boldsymbol k|\boldsymbol k\rangle$,
3. Or an identity on their expectation values,
   $$
   \langle\psi|\hat{\boldsymbol p}|\psi\rangle=\hbar \langle\psi|\hat{\boldsymbol k}|\psi\rangle
   \tag3
   $$

The **answer** is that all these statements are **correct**, the most fundamental being $(1)$ (and the other two being trivial consequences). More precisely, $(1)$ is just the *definition* of the operator $\hat{\boldsymbol k}$. The fact that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ and $(3)$ is immediate, and is left as an exercise to the reader. The same conclusion holds in curved spacetime and/or relativistic QM (the only difference being that $\boldsymbol p,\boldsymbol k$ are to be regarded as elements of the tangent space, but this makes no difference from an algebraic point of view).